# E/flutter ( 3045): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)]

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

E/flutter ( 3045): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List' has no instance method 'call'.

this is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(IniApp) => runApp(IniApp(home: IniApp()));

class IniApp extends StatelessWidget { 
  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return MaterialApp( 
      home: Scaffold( 
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("who's is emir"),), 
        body: Column( 
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, 
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, 
          children:[ 
            Center( 
              child:  Center(
              child: Text("Nama Saya Emir Afawan\n"
                  "NIM Saya 20180801028\n"
                  "Hobby Saya Volleyball\n"
                  "Pekerjaan Saya Kuliah\n"
                  "Status Saya Belajar"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello !

It seems that you have two main in the code you shared, also one of them has a `return M;` ?
Can you edit your post and clarify your formating.

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main function has a strange behavior, trying to call IniApp with a home argument that does not exist. Try to simplify it by calling it once as such: `void main() => runApp(IniApp());`